# I want to import my Json file into a custom made display-modal. How do i link my Json file?

Tags: jquery, javascript, json

I have a custom modal, to display the employees of Inhouse Graphic, and i have a Json file that keeps all the data. I use JS to parse the data into my modal, and it works fine on a non WP website. When i tried to import the same Json file into wordpress it didn't work, i get this ERROR:
GET http://localhost/ihg/mediegrafiker-2/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/data.json 404 (Not Found).

This is my code to import the Json data:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('.modal-btn').click(function () {
var jsonFilename = "http://localhost/ihg/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/data.json";
    var newImage;
    var newName;
    var newAdresse;
    var newAge;
    var newDate;
    var newMail;    
    var newWeb;
    var newIn;
    var newPresentation;
    var newPres1;
    var newPres2;
    var newPres3;
    var newPres4;
    var newPres5;

    /* defining ID for the data*/

    idValue = $('.modal').attr('id').replace('myModalmg', '');

    /* refering to the data*/

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        newImage = data.personer[idValue].billede;
        newName = data.personer[idValue].navn;
        newAdresse = data.personer[idValue].bosat;
        newAge = data.personer[idValue].alder;
        newDate = data.personer[idValue].dato;
        newMail = data.personer[idValue].email;
        newWeb = data.personer[idValue].website;
        newIn = data.personer[idValue].linkedin;
        newPresentation = data.personer[idValue].præsentation;
        newPres1 = data.personer[idValue].pres1;
        newPres2 = data.personer[idValue].pres2;
        newPres3 = data.personer[idValue].pres3;
        newPres4 = data.personer[idValue].pres4;
        newPres5 = data.personer[idValue].pres5;

        console.log();

        /* inserting the data*/

        console.log(newImage + ", " + newName + ", " + newAdresse + ", " + newAge + " år, " + newDate + ", " + newMail + ", " + newWeb + ", " + newIn + ", Personlig tekst");

    }).done(function () {
        $('#profile-img').attr('src', newImage);
        $('#navn').text(newName);
        $('#bosat').text(newAdresse);
        $('#alder').text(newAge);
        $('#dato').text(newDate);
        $('#email').attr('href', newMail);
        $('#website').attr('href', newWeb);
        $('#linked-in').attr('href', newIn);
        $('#presentation').text(newPresentation);
        $('.remove').remove();
        if (newPres1.length > 0) {
            $(".modal-body").append($('<div class="doublespace remove"></div>'))
            $(".modal-body").append($('<p class="p_standard remove" id="pres-1"></p>'));
            $('#pres-1').text(newPres1);
        };
        if (newPres2.length > 0) {
            $(".modal-body").append($('<div class="doublespace remove"></div>'))
            $(".modal-body").append($('<p class="p_standard remove" id="pres-2"></p>'));
            $('#pres-2').text(newPres2);
        };
        if (newPres3.length > 0) {
            $(".modal-body").append($('<div class="doublespace remove"></div>'))
            $(".modal-body").append($('<p class="p_standard remove" id="pres-3"></p>'));
            $('#pres-3').text(newPres3);
        };
        if (newPres4.length > 0) {
            $(".modal-body").append($('<div class="doublespace remove"></div>'))
            $(".modal-body").append($('<p class="p_standard remove" id="pres-4"></p>'));
            $('#pres-4').text(newPres4);
        };
        if (newPres5.length > 0) {
            $(".modal-body").append($('<div class="doublespace remove"></div>'))
            $(".modal-body").append($('<p class="p_standard remove" id="pres-5"></p>'));
            $('#pres-5').text(newPres5);
        };
});
});
```

I find it impossible to link my Json file within Wordpress.
What is the ususal way to import Json data and is there a way without using the Json API (since I don't see the logic of it)?